# Fragment Life cycle from onPause to OnResume

Tags: android-fragments, state, android-lifecycle

In Activity life cycle we can go from OnPause to Onresume directly (this can occur if our activity leaves the foreground but is still visible, i.e. a dialog pop ups).  Checking the fragment life cycle diagram:  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

When the activity is paused then the fragments respective onPause is called.  But at this point when the activity call onResume what state is the fragment in ? What life cycle callback gets called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onResume as well, check the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onResume()

Answer (score 1):

The Fragment lifecycle is tied to the Activity lifecycle. If the Activity is changing the state the Fragment will aswell. Because of that a Fragment has the same major lifecycle components as an Activity like onCreate(), onResume and so on. In addition to these, there are some specific ones like onAttached(), onDetached(), onActivityCreated() etc.

A Fragment is able to draw an UI and is controlled by the Activity. If that wouldn't be the case some strange things could happen. Like the Activity goes into the background but the Fragment is still visible. That's why these two components have to sync their state.

Comment: Thanks i upvoted your answer. I needed a direct answer which fasteque gave me.  Fragments are tied to the activity so if an activities onResume gets called, then so will the fragments onResume etc.  Thanks for the clarification.